# How do I delete a certain line from a file with Perl?

Tags: shell-script, perl

How would I delete the line

```
[[ -f /var/tmp/Li.ksh ]] && /var/tmp/Li.ksh
```

from a file by a perl command in a ksh script?

I tried:

```
perl -i -pe "s/[[ -f /var/tmp/Li.ksh ]] && /var/tmp/Li.ksh//" /etc/tl.conf
```

But I got:

```
Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[ <-- HERE [ -f / at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

`[`, `.`,  and `/` have a special meaning in a regular expression. You have to escape them:

```
perl -i -pe "s/\[\[\ -f\ \/var\/tmp\/Li\.ksh\ \]\]\ &&\ \/var\/tmp\/Li\.ksh//"
```

EDIT: beware that this will not delete the line but just remove the text you have in the regex. If if it the whole line a blank line will remain.

More readable version (use brackets to define the regex so that you don't have to escape `/`):

```
perl -i -pe "s{\[\[ -f /var/tmp/Li.ksh \]\] && /var/tmp/Li\.ksh}{}"
```

But, since you are asking about a shell script, why use Perl and not `grep -v` (`--invert-match`)?

```
grep -v '[[ -f /var/tmp/Li.ksh ]] && /var/tmp/Li.ksh' /etc/tl.conf
```

Comment: I not want to write to other file as /etc/tl.conf , I want to  edit only file  /var/tmp/tl.conf , about the perl seems good but I need simpler option , you used "\" many time in the lines !

Comment: @diana Ok then just escape the special characters as suggested.

Comment: maybe you have some other trick in perl in order not to use the "\" ?

Comment: @diana There a couple of tricks but in general you have to escape special characters if you want to use a regular expression.

Comment: did you live near the hospital "inselspital" in bern?

Comment: @diana Not really.

Comment: @diana, @Matteo: You can use `\Q` to escape all following special characters. This avoids the need for inserting all those `\\` characters.

Answer (score 1):

File before

```
$ cat t.txt
aaa
[[ -f /var/tmp/Li.ksh ]] && /var/tmp/Li.ksh
bbb
```

Command (using \Q to ignore the specialness of special characters in the regular expression)

```
$ perl -i -lne 'print unless m{\Q[[ -f /var/tmp/Li.ksh ]] && /var/tmp/Li.ksh}' t.txt
```

File after

```
$ cat t.txt
aaa
bbb
```

Note:
Change `-i` to `-i.bak` if you want perl to make a backup of the file before the changes.

You can also do it this way (using simple text equality test, no regex).

```
$ perl -i -lne 'print unless $_ eq q([[ -f /var/tmp/Li.ksh ]] && /var/tmp/Li.ksh)' t.txt
```

Comment: +1 for both `eq` and `\Q`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got something that will work for you, basicly I am reading in the current file and outputting a "modified" version of the file minus the matching line (the one mentioned in the question). It seems to work for me when I test it. Please Please DO NOT try this until you make a backup just in case it goes wrong.

here is the code, change the file name to suit your needs then run the script it "should" work.

Its not very pretty but it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file = "sample.txt";
my $out_file = "control.txt";

open INFILE , "<", $in_file;
open OUTFILE,  ">", $out_file;

my @array;

while (<INFILE>) {

    push @array, $_;

}

foreach my $line (@array) {

    if ( $line =~ /(\"\[\[\s*\-f\s*\/var\/tmp\/Li\.ksh\s*\]\]\s*\&\&\s*\/var\/tmp\/Li.ksh\")/xm ) {

        print "I have ommited the following line $1\n";

    } else {

        print OUTFILE "$line";

    }

}

close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;
```